# SSL Pinning Error - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate

I am trying to implement POST API which is secured, it needs to be authenticated using a self-signed certificate. I added a self-signed certificate in a bundle and handled the challenge inside delegate method *didReceiveChallenge*, I feel certificate has been successfully validated but always getting an error with Code=-999.